# Access: Invalid UPDATE statement

Tags: c#, ms-access

I'm trying to update a table in Access database. But when I debug I get the exception: "Invalid UPDATE statement". What's wrong with my statement:

```
string query = @"UPDATE Phone SET Name = ?, Number = ? WHERE ID = ?";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both [number and name are reserved words](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/sql-reserved-words-HP001032249.aspx), so shold be enclosed in brackets [Name].